# Are these SSD temperatures too high?

Tags: mac, ssd, external-hard-drive, smart, thunderbolt

```
$ sudo smartctl -a disk1 | egrep 'Model|Sensor'
Model Number:                       Samsung Portable SSD X5
Temperature Sensor 1:               51 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               73 Celsius
```

This is on a Mac Mini with the X5 connected externally via Thunderbolt.

What is the difference between the two sensors and are these values too high?

Comment: A general rule of thumb, or at least the one that I follow, is to only become concerned when temps are hitting 80C+.  SSDs will get quite hot when doing continuous writes.  If Samsung's SSDs hit their critical temp threshold, their controller should auto unmount themselves, which happens quite frequently to me if I'm doing a massive file copy to one of my 850 EVO mSATAs in a passively cooled, all-metal USB-C Orico case.  If you're extremely concerned, place the SSD in a position that puts the most surface area off a surface and put a small fan in front of it (a tiny USB fan works well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Samsung X5 has two internal temperature sensors that measure case and controller temperatures.

Your temperature measures look normal.

In Toms Hardware article
[Samsung 1TB Portable SSD X5 Review](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/samsung-portable-ssd-x5-nvme-thunderbolt-3,5779-2.html),
you can see this test, where the temperatures are very similar to yours:

[image]